# Winforms application getting crashed on running this code

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

When i execute the following piece of codes, the application hangs up. Am i doing something wrong here?

Note: Even if i don't have thread.sleep, the application is still crashing.
In fact i have added to stop it from crashing.

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        boolValue = true;
        while (boolValue)
        {
            counter++; //Class Variable =0 by default
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lbl.Text = counter.ToString();               
        }
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        boolValue = true;
        while (boolValue)
        {
            counter++; //Class Variable =0 by default

            lbl.Text = counter.ToString();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: You tell it to sleep forever. What did you expect?

Comment: If you want to have a counter displayed, use a timer mechanism.

Comment: See my answer! You are building endless loop. Somewhere in your loop you have to change boolValue to false. Else the loop cant stop at any time.

Comment: I want the loop to be infinite and display the updated counter values in the label.

Comment: @Nuclear-Core Yes but you have to define a end. The loop runs endless. So your System cant do any other work because it has to run your loop. This is the point why your System cant response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never change `boolValue` value.The code will be in an endless loop.If You want to display the counter's value, you can use Class `Timer`.

```
private Timer myTimer = new Timer();

private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)     
{       
  lbl.Text = counter.ToString();  
  counter++;
}

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);      
   myTimer.Interval = 1000;
   myTimer.Start();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Spark. But could you please elaborate why my application is crashing with the present code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the boolValue = false somewhere in your loop. Its endless loop.

For example:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    boolValue = true;
    while (boolValue)
    {
        counter++; //Class Variable =0 by default
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lbl.Text = counter.ToString();

        if (counter == int.MaxValue)
        {
           boolValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

A much better solution is to use the Timer Component instead of while()!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a counter displayed, see @Spark's answer.
Otherwise add the following command inside the loop and you have to think endless loop:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```